# OpenAI Gym: gym.make() does not refer to updated Env code

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am building my a custom Gym environment and so far everything worked well following the guides spread all over the internet. However, I am now in a phase when frequent changes to the environment class (inheriting gym.Env) are happening and need to be tested. After the latest coding changes to `reset()` and `step()` method, it turns out that now `gym.make()` returns an environment object which executes **old code which was valid before**.

So my question is: **How to overcome that issue?**
I am not a friend of increasing the version id to e.g. v1, as the originating v0 is still under development.

The `__init__.py` file on package level contains that:

```
from importlib.metadata import version
from gym.envs.registration import register

__version__ = version("wksim")
register(id="WkEnv-v0", entry_point="wksim.wkenv:WkEnv")
```

*Note: class WkEnv is located in the file wkenv.py*

In the following executable file I am testing the following way

```
import gym
from wksim.wkenv import WkEnv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    env_config = {
        "cli_mode": True,
        "cache_trace": True,
        "instance": "minimal",
        "UNIFORM_TIME_SLOT_LENGTH": 0.05,
    }

    env = gym.make("WkEnv-v0", config=env_config)
    initial_state = env.reset()
```

*Note: I learnt that the custom environment class must be imported, otherwise gym.make() will not find the env id.*

Comment: What version of gym are you using?

Comment: Your issue might be due to the gym version. If I don't know the gym version, it could be impossible to detect the source of the problem.

Comment: I use gym version 0.21.0 in order to have compatibility with ray-rllib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This topic was solved even with `gym` 0.21.0, but also now after the upgrade to `gymnasium`. The root cause was sitting in the way of how the overall package was installed. Using `pip install -e` solved the point.